# Format strings c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, string-formatting

I'm new to c++, and can't find how to set different file names every time a loop is running. I want to make a new file every time the loop is running, and of course I have to give them different file names. Otherwise the same file is just updating. In Python it can easily be done by

```
for i in range(10):
    filename = "myfile%f.dat" % i
```

but I can't find a similar syntax in c++. I hope someone can help me, I made a example script below (with Python syntax for the format string) which hopefully makes it more clear what I'm trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 11; i += 1)
    {
        string filename; filename = "table%d.dat"%i;
        ofstream infile;
        infile.open( filename.c_str());
        infile << "multiplication table for " << i << endl;
        for(int j = 1; j < 11; j+=1)
        {
            infile << j*i << endl;
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::to_string`, `std::ostringstream`, `sprintf`...

Comment: `string filename = "table" + std::to_string(i) + ".dat";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives:

1. Use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and string concatenation:

   ```
   std::string filename = "table" + std::to_string(i) + ".dat";
   ```
2. Use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

   ```
   std::ostringstream iss;
   iss << "table" << i << ".dat";
   std::string filename = iss.str();
   ```

Comment: Explicit conversion of `"table"` to `std::string` is not necessary, I think.

Comment: @LogicStuff: It helps maintenance to have a `std::string` at the start, so that modifying the rest doesn't break the code.

Comment: Just to help nordhagen out, #include <sstream> for ostringstream

Answer (score 2):

Use of string stream might help:

```
std::stringstream filenamebuffer;
buffer << "table" << i << ".dat";
filename = filenamebuffer.str()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try _snprintf_s. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f30dzcf6.aspx

```
//...
char buffer[20];
if(_snprintf(buffer, 20, 20, "table%d.dat", i);
infile.open(buffer);
//...
```